# ggplot2: How to add padding/gap to segment end points

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
library(ggplot2)

dfr1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2))
dfr2 <- data.frame(x=1,xend=2,y=1,yend=2)

ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=dfr1,aes(x,y),size=6)+
  geom_segment(data=dfr2,aes(x=xend,y=yend,xend=x,yend=y), color="red",arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.10,"cm"), ends="first", type = "closed"))+
  coord_fixed()+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I would like to add some padding/gap to the start and end of the segment so that they do not overlap the points. Here is a manually edited image to show what I mean:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  version  R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#>  os       Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.6   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `ggh4x::geom_pointpath` which

> is used to make a scatterplot wherein the points are connected with lines in some order.

and automatically adds some padding which could be specified via the `mult` argument. However, TBMK it does not allow for different colored points and lines so I added a `geom_point` on top of it.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

dfr1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(1, 2))

ggplot(dfr1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_pointpath(
    color = "red", size = 6, mult = .25,
    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.10, "cm"), ends = "last", type = "closed")
  ) +
  geom_point(size = 6) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this manually:

```r
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=dfr1,aes(x,y),size=6)+
  geom_segment(data=dfr2,
               aes(x = xend - 0.03,
                   y = yend - 0.03,
                   xend = x + 0.03,
                   yend = y + 0.03,), 
               color="red",arrow = arrow(length=unit(0.10,"cm"), ends="first", type = "closed"))+
  coord_fixed()+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I have ended up doing, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way. Also unit independent and not having to tinker with the data.

Comment: So far I've not found a solution other than this one...